# Why is my dataflow pipeline not showing that it can't insert into BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

I've written a Dataflow pipeline in Go that reads from a Pub/Sub subscription, performs a transformation, and then writes the record to BigQuery.

It seemingly runs fine, but I can't see the data in my BigQuery table.

Viewing the pipeline and reading the logs, I can't see any errors that might explain this. How do I go about debugging failed BigQuery insertions from Dataflow?

Comment: Did you find any error in the worker logs of the pipeline?<br>

Comment: have you walked through this tutorial? https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/tutorials/dataflow-stream-to-bigquery